# WPF: "Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'."

Tags: .net, wpf, image, data-binding

I'm trying to set a WPF Image's source.

**XAML** works:

```
<Image Name="ImageThing"
       Source="images/Thing.png"/>
```

**Visual Basic** fails:

```
ImageThing.Source = "images/Thing.png"
```

…with this **exception**:

> Value of type 'String' cannot be
>   converted to
>   'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'.

How do I create the System.Windows.Media.ImageSource that I need?

---

### Update

This code adapted from an [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) works:

```
Dim bmp As New BitmapImage()
bmp.BeginInit()
bmp.UriSource = New Uri("images/Thing.png", UriKind.Relative)
bmp.EndInit()
ImageThing.Source = bmp
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WPF uses an implicit type converter to convert the xaml string to the expected type.  In code you are statically bound by the object type...  If you look at the [example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) it shows how to set the source property to a BitmapImage that is generated from a local uri programatically.

Answer (score 7):

you will probably need to do something like this

```
Uri i = new Uri("images\\Thing.png");
```

keep in mind that you need to use a \ not a / for a windows file system

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

It can be even easier than the above:

`ImageThing.Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri("images/Thing.png", UriKind.Relative))`

Answer (score 1):

Just change xaml file like this.

```xaml
<Image Name="ImageThing">
    <Image.Source>
       <BitmapImage UriSource="images/Thing.png" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Answer (score -2):

What about

```
Private Sub Google_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Mainbrowser.Navigate("http://www.contoso.com")
```

Comment: Did you answer the wrong question? This doesn't appear to relate at all.