# XAML - Dynamics set UriSource in BitmapIcon

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

I'm developing Windows Phone 8.1 app. If I set UriSource in BitmapIcon control like:

```
<BitmapIcon Width="35" Height="35" Margin="0" RequestedTheme="Dark" UriSource="/Assets/Main/Operations/appbar.information.png">
```

all works fine, but if I want to set it dynamics I see still empty field.

I'm using MVVM Light. My model looks like :

```
    ...
    private string _icon;
    public string Icon
    {
        get { return _icon; }
        set { _icon = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Icon"); }
    }
    ...
```

Next I create object, add to list and on this base create observable collection. Other fields work properly, but not this:

```
<BitmapIcon Width="25" Height="25" Margin="0" UriSource="{Binding Icon, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BitmapIcon.UriSource` is of type `Uri` not `string`. You should use this instead:

```
private Uri _icon;
public Uri Icon
{
    get { return _icon; }
    set { _icon = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Icon"); }
}
```

Then in your view model, you'd set the icon like this:

```
Icon = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Main/Operations/appbar.information.png");
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/702624/734040) explains why using a string in the XAML works but not in C# code.